# How to Store salt and hashed password Database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

My login function in ASP.Net Web application i planed to go for a better security way so i have googled a lot and finally I found: CrackStation.net. It was really amazing.. the question is they didn't mention how to store salt and hashed password in database. Here is a the code found on Crack Station. I also have a [DotNetFiddle Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cHmZeD) you can run in your browser.

i want to know how to store password in database (slat and hash both concatenate and save in one column) or (each in different columns such as salt is salt column and hash is hash column)...

Please step by step explain the password salting and hashing processing up to save in database and retrieve from database and varify...

Is salt and hash are a same?

At what time we generate salt (random salt)? Why we save salt in separate column in sql database?? Saved salt in database column at which time we need to use?

Please clearly mention. (Any source code examples.)

Thank you.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: so you want to repeat a single Row n times

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure this what you want.

Just to show you an example am answering this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 AS rn
         UNION ALL
         SELECT rn + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  rn < 3) -- Count
SELECT id
FROM   cte
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1003 id) B
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't make much of a difference, you can have salt and hash in seperate columns, or concatenate them and put them in one column ([clarification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76137/separate-database-column-for-salt)). Having them in seperate columns is easier.
2. You create the salt before you calculate the hash.

To verify that a password is correct:

- Transmit the candidate password (CP) to your server over a
  secure channel
- Retrieve the hash (H) and the salt (S) from the database.
- Calculate a candidate hash (CH) using the candidate password (CP) and the salt (S)
- Compare the candidate hash (CH) with the hash (H)

Make sure that no hash or salt is ever transmitted to the client.

Comment: Note that your question is not very clear, so my answers may not be answering what you think you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! when i concatenate salt + hash and stored in one column how to retrieve and verifies that the a password matches the specified hash and salt values???

Comment: @user1663855 I would suggest storing the salt and hash in seperate columns. It's just easier that way.

Comment: Thanks.. than what about ITERATIONS = 10000; Can you explain this in sample code (any source code preferred)

Comment: @user1663855 That is more than what your question is about. Plus I haven't coded in C#/.NET for more than 7 years. Personally I think 10K iterations is on the low side.

Comment: Thank you very much @TT. i couldn't understand this part - Calculate a candidate hash (CH) using the candidate password (CP) and the salt (S)

Comment: @M.I.M.F You calculate a candidate hash the same way you calculate the actual hash, but instead you use the candidate password - i.e. the password with which the user is attempting to log in.

Comment: i couldn't understand what calculate you are saying @TT. Thanks